# IntelliJ pytest BDD with python - unable to navigate from Feature file to step definition

Tags: python, automation, cucumber, pytest, bdd

I have to write automation script using pytest BDD and python. I wrote a sample automation script and created feature file and step definition for the same. The code runs fine and identifies the steps provided in the feature file.

However when I am trying to navigate from feature file (CTRL+CLICK) to step definition, it shows an error "Cannot not find declaration to go to".

I have searched all over the internet and tried different steps mentioned but nothing worked. I also uninstalled and reinstalled the intelliJ IDE but not luck.

Then I imported another project which was written in java with cucumber and facing same issue.

Am I missing some settings on IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have JetBrain's `Gherkin` plugin installed or enabled.

This plugin enables navigation between feature files and cucumber steps in source code. Also it helps for gherkin syntax coloring.

I use also a plugin called [Cucumber +](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16289-cucumber-)
Give a try.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: I have gherkin plugin enabled. I also tried Cucumber+ plugin. but no luck. Just FYI .. I am using IntelliJ community edition

Comment: `Gherkin` plugin works for all IntelliJ based IDEs.

Can you check if your feature files are associated by Cucumber scenario? `Settings > File Types > Cucumber scenario > *.feature`

If this does not work I would clear caches or clear .idea folder at last resort :(

Comment: I tried both but still not able to navigate